# Why is AppCentre uncurated install not visible in Applications menu or command line?

Tags: release-hera, wine

I installed Wine using AppCentre. This simple first step spawned a dozen questions, so I hope if I stop and ask one discrete question at a time it will be key to my understanding. I thought I'd try ADE again, from scratch but baby steps.

I was warned "uncurated," then it installed without a snag. After install I was given:

- a generic icon with blank name under Applications/Accessories
- a proper icon and v7.0.0.0 under AppCentre/Installed list
- new and expected directories with contents, like ~/.wine

The first thing I did was open the Terminal to check the version but nothing was available, and if Wine doesn't have a graphic interface it doesn't make sense that an installer wouldn't create a required environment. Is no environment the expected result, and are there Linux assumptions that I'm misunderstanding? I don't want to automatically switch to apt if I don't know the problem I'm solving.